# Android Выбор Activity при старте

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть MainActivity и при его старте вызывается AlertDialog в котором спрашивается какую активность запустить первую или вторую. При выборе запускается другая активность и нужно сделать так, чтобы она была главной. То есть когда я запускаю последующую активити и нажимаю кнопку назад, она выбрасывает меня на MainActivity. Я пробовал ставить разный setContentView(), но проблема в том, что после выбора xml файл не накладывался.

Comment: В чем проблема ?вопрос какойто запутанный

Comment: пробови через meta сделать корневм родителем?

Answer (score 1):

Прошу ответ исправил

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Наоборот, мне надо чтобы последующая активити (не родительская) закрывала всё приложение при нажатии "Назад"

Comment: АААА ну так этож ещё легче добвте метод финиш щас секу исправ отв